# What will be the GSQL procedure for retrieving all nodes and relationships in Tiger Graph?

Tags: graph, graph-databases, tigergraph

I recently started working on Tiger Graph and looking for the GSQL procedure for retrieving all nodes and relationships. Just like in Cypher, we have the query Match (n) Return n. I couldn't able to find any specific answer for the same query with GSQL.

Answer (score 1):

In Neo4j

```
Match (n) Return n
```

will give you only all the nodes without relations.

In Tiger you should write:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE QUERY generated_query() FOR GRAPH graphName SYNTAX V3 {
VS= SELECT n
  FROM   (n);

  PRINT VS;
}
```

If you wish to get all nodes and relations,
For Neo4j:

```
Match (n)-[r]-(a) Return n,r,a
```

and for Tiger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE QUERY generated_query() FOR GRAPH openCypher_Movie SYNTAX V3 {
    SELECT n,r,a INTO T
    FROM   (n)-[r]-(a);

    PRINT T;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I admit that doing this is easier in Cypher, but there you go:

```
CREATE QUERY allOfIt() FOR GRAPH MyGraph {  
  ListAccum <EDGE> @@allE;
  G = {ANY};

  G2 = SELECT s FROM G:s-(:e)->:t 
  ACCUM @@allE += e
  HAVING 1==0;

  PRINT G, @@allE;
}
```